# how set proxy in windows tunnel my traffic to my android phone

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, android, putty

I am trying to establish an ssh tunnel to my android phone from my windows phone.

from putty I can do `ssh root@android:port2` 
but on Linux servers there is an option -D from terminal i.e.

```
ssh -D port1 root@andoidphone:port2
```

and then in system wide network settings I can apply manual proxy for system 
 localhost   and port as port1 used in ssh connection.

That way I can tunnel my traffic to my android phone.

I am trying to do same on my windows 10 laptop.
But in putty 
1) I do not know how to set ssh -D port option.
2) The proxy configuration I am setting in run-->network proxy settings--->manual proxy setup [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM8e9.jpg)
Here what ever I am setting and then saving each time it is getting erased so I am not able to test my system if it is able to access internet via my android phone. How can I stabilise this manual proxy setup in Windows 10?